# SQL IF ELSE Statement not executing

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I've the following prepared statement that I'm trying to create for my shopping cart but it  won't execute correctly.  It reports the following error and I don't know how to fix it:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; END $$' at line 25**

As far as I know the IF statement syntax is correct but it just wont work.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE shopping_cart_add_product(IN inCartId CHAR(32),
IN inProductId INT, IN inAttributes VARCHAR(1000))
BEGIN
DECLARE productQuantity INT;

SELECT quantity
FROM shopping_cart
WHERE cart_id = inCartId
AND product_id = inProductId
AND attributes = inAttributes
INTO productQuantity;

IF productQuantity IS NULL THEN
INSERT INTO shopping_cart(cart_id, product_id, attributes,
productQuantityuantity, added_on)
VALUES (inCartId, inProductId, inAttributes, 1, NOW());

ELSE  
UPDATE shopping_cart
SET quantity = quantity + 1, buy_now = true
WHERE cart_id = inCartId
AND product_id = inProductId
AND attributes = inAttributes;
ENDIF;
END $$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove $$ after END $$ and add space between END and IF

```
    END IF;
    END $$
```

Comment: Bingo!!  I can't believe I missed that, I thought i'd tried every variation of those last two lines.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be END IF not ENDIF on the second line from the bottom.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

```
...
ELSE  
UPDATE shopping_cart
SET quantity = quantity + 1, buy_now = true
WHERE cart_id = inCartId
AND product_id = inProductId
AND attributes = inAttributes;
END IF;
END $$
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for quick reply.  I trie that already and now I get an error with the next line. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$' at line 2